# Android - Adding custom Modifiers in jetpack

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to add some semantics

```
contentDescription = "SomeID"
testTag = "SomeID"
```

to some UI elements

Current approach is like this

```
modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 10).semantics {
    testTag = "SomeID"
    contentDescription = "SomeID"
},
```

How do write a custom extension that takes in input data and assigns it to **semantics**

```
modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 10).addSemantics(id = "SomeID"),
```

Comment: Note that `contentDescription` is supposed to be a human-readable string explaining the role of the UI element. The content description is read out to users via TalkBack and other assistive technologies. It should not be an identifier. That being said, a fair bit has been written about creating creating custom modifiers, such as [this Medium post](https://proandroiddev.com/deep-dive-into-modifiers-jetpack-compose-a2605da4b88a).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as

```
fun Modifier.customModifier(paddingValues: PaddingValues, description: String) = this.then(
    padding(paddingValues).semantics {
        testTag = description
        contentDescription = description
    }
)
```

When you wish your Modifier to have memory or access to Comopsable scope to use LaunchedEffect and so on you can use `composed` as

```
fun Modifier.customModifierWithMemory(paddingValues: PaddingValues, description: String) =
    composed {
        LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit){
            // Do something here
        }

        var memory by remember {
            mutableStateOf(0)
        }
        Modifier
            .padding(paddingValues)
            .semantics {
                testTag = description
                contentDescription = description
            }
    }
```